# Microsoft Access Form Setting Default Value to Previous Entry for Both Text Boxes and Drop Down Lists

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to make it so that for my Microsoft Access form when I add a new record, the fields are populated with values from my previous entry.

For regular text boxes, I used the following code in the before update section:

```
    Private Sub Field_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Me![Field].DefaultValue = Me![Field].Value
    End Sub
```

However, I am unable to make this work with Date fields or with drop down menu fields.

Answer (score 0):

What happens - error message, wrong results, nothing?

For date field, try: `Me.controlname.DefaultValue = "#" & Me.controlname & "#"`

For the combobox, is it saving a text value? Try:
`Me.controlname.DefaultValue = "'" & Me.controlname & "'"`