# Passing the value on a textbox control to a new record using the same form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form which comprise of a texbox bound to a field called Year1. I want to create a new record using the new record controls in the bottom of the form and have the value on the previous record carried forward to the new record. I tried the following codes but no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated. Below is my first approach:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblMyTable")
rs.AddNew
rs.Fields("Year1").Value = Year1.Value

rs.Close

End Sub
```

I have also tried the following approach but no luck:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblMyTable")
     rs.Edit
     rs!Year1 = Year1.Value
     rs.Update
  rs.Close
  End Sub
```

Comment: One approach is to set control's DefaultValue property. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44334044/microsoft-access-form-setting-default-value-to-previous-entry-for-both-text-boxe. Set the property when a first record of edit session is entered or do the lookup on existing records or some combination of the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the     Year1_AfterUpdate()     even, adding:

```
Me.Year1.DefaultValue = "'" & Me.Year1 & "'"
```

Works as expected.