# Set the Default Value of a Field to the Value held by the First Record in the Table, without a Form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a long table and sometimes users want to insert new records on the table. I want the default values on a field to be the value held by the first record of that same column. At first I thought inserting the code below in the field properties through the design view would work but no luck!

```
  =[Year1].ItemData(0)
```

Comment: As those values are fixed if it's the first record, why not simply set the default value to that value. You can't make it a calculated field as that wouldn't allow editing.
You probably can write a VBA code to do this at table def level, but I doubt the time spent writing it would be worth the effort, as it's a one off operation?

Comment: Hey @Minty, the problem is the value is allowed to be changed through a form although the entire field holds the same value. The reason to setting a default value is in case someone creates a new record via the back end, the value would be automatically singed.

Comment: You shouldn't ever let anyone near the actual table, so you shouldn't need to really account for this. You can set a different default value on a form that will override the tables underlying default value.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the default value property of a field cannot reference other objects in the database - it can only be constant or calculated from a constant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing the value on a textbox control to a new record using the same form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48757596/passing-the-value-on-a-textbox-control-to-a-new-record-using-the-same-form)

Comment: @braX, I don't think this is a duplicate, as in this thread the OP is trying to set the default value for fields in the table itself, not records displayed on a form.

Comment: The point is it's not practical to dynamically set DefaultValue of field in table as that requires design modification using TableDefs and code in some event. And the only way to code behind tables is with DataMacros. Don't allow users to interact with tables and queries, only forms and reports.

Comment: So what is the value in that first record? Just set the DefaultValue property to that value in the table design. Use code behind form to dynamically change the DefaultValue.

Comment: Sorry, but i Don't get it. If you want always the default value to be the first one in your table and you already got records in that table, and supossing the table is always the same, then, why can't you just type it manually?

Comment: The field holds a value that can be modified through a TextBox in a form. Some Users prefer to modify the records directly on the table. This cause problems if the user forgets to input the value on the field. It's even more painful since this value is a date. I have even consdered creating a separate table that temporarily holds the value of the first record and then making the default value of the field in the main table point to the value held by this temporal table. Is this even possible?