# Setting Form Field to autopopulate with previous record entry for text, date, and combo box

Tags: vba, ms-access, default-value, autofill

I am still very new to most vba coding. I'm trying to do pretty much the exact same thing as with this post:
[Microsoft Access Form Setting Default Value to Previous Entry for Both Text Boxes and Drop Down Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44334044/microsoft-access-form-setting-default-value-to-previous-entry-for-both-text-boxe)
but nothing from it seems to be working for me. I want to populate each field in the form with the previous record's data via a button `Autofill_Click()`

```
Private Sub Autofill_Click()

    Me!DateTimeID.DefaultValue = Me![DateTimeID].Value
    Me.frmDate.DefaultValue = "#" & Me.frmDate & "#"
    Me.Location.DefaultValue = "'" & Me.Location & "'"
    
End Sub
```

I'm receiving the error code "type mismatch" for the first line with DateTimeID, as well as an error code "There is an invalid use of the . or ! operator or invalid parentheses." for the second line with frmDate. The third line isn't even throwing an error code, but it isn't populating the desired field (or any field, for that matter) with what I want.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try changing the first line to `Me.DateTimeID.DefaultValue = Me.DateTimeID.Value` and seeing if that changes anything. The first error usually causes the other errors, so I typically focus primarily on it.

Comment: If frmDate is a form, forms don't have DefaultValue. Field will not populate until record edit is initiated by input into any control for a new record. What field type is DateTimeID?

Comment: @jonnyHenly I tried changing that, and it throws an error code saying "invalid use of null". I also tried commenting out the first line so that it would automatically run to the second, and that's where I got the second error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @June7 frmDate is not a form, I have it named that from a previous user. It is just a date field. DateTimeID is a short text field type, it can contain numbers, letters, and characters from the user.

Comment: @June7 Sorry, I'm not sure if I tagged your name correctly in the above response.

Comment: Is `DateTimeID` an Access or SQL reserved word? That would be the only reason to enclose it in brackets (`[]`). Perhaps try `Me![DateTimeID].DefaultValue = Me![DateTimeID].Value`

Answer (score 0):

For text:

`Me.[DateTimeID].DefaultValue = "'" & Me.[DateTimeID] & "'"`

For date/time:

`Me.frmDate.DefaultValue = "#" & Me.frmDate & "#"`

For number:

`Me.Quantity.DefaultValue = Me.Quantity`

Code is usually put in control's AfterUpdate event so user doesn't have to do anything other than normal data entry/edit.